# What's the purpose of passing MPI_Gather a recvtype not equal to the sendtype?

Tags: mpi, mpich

Consider the [MPICH docs](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_Gather.html) for the function `MPI_Gather` quoted below. It takes the arguments `sendtype` and `recvtype`.
When does it make sense to not pass the same type, e.g. `MPI_FLOAT` or `MPI_DOUBLE`, for both?

I ask because it seems useless to have to pass the same argument twice, so MPI probably has a reason for accepting both a receive- and a sendtype.

> **MPI_Gather**
>   Gathers together values from a group of processes
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
> int MPI_Gather(const void *sendbuf, int sendcount, MPI_Datatype sendtype,
>                void *recvbuf, int recvcount, MPI_Datatype recvtype,
>                int root, MPI_Comm comm)
> ```
>
> **Input Parameters**
>
> ```
> sendbuf
>     starting address of send buffer (choice)
> sendcount
>     number of elements in send buffer (integer)
> sendtype
>     data type of send buffer elements (handle)
> recvcount
>     number of elements for any single receive (integer, significant only at root)
> recvtype
>     data type of recv buffer elements (significant only at root) (handle)
> root
>     rank of receiving process (integer)
> comm
>     communicator (handle)
> ```
>
> **Output Parameters**
>
> ```
> recvbuf
>      address of receive buffer (choice, significant only at root)
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MPI only requires matching signatures.

For example you could send 10 `MPI_INT` and receive 1 derived datatype which is a vector of 10 `MPI_INT`.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness' sake, I'm also quoting Gilles' answer.

> MPI only requires matching signatures.
>
> For example you could send 10 `MPI_INT` and receive 1 derived datatype
>   which is a vector of 10 `MPI_INT`.

[Gilles Gouaillardet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50077481/2550406%20Gilles%20Gouaillardet's%20answer) contains the very helpful remark about a "derived datatype" which led me to [this explanation by Victor Eijkhout at the Texas Advanced Computing Center](http://pages.tacc.utexas.edu/~eijkhout/pcse/html/mpi-data.html).

> A vector type describes a series of blocks, all of equal size, spaced
>   with a constant stride. [...] The vector datatype gives the first
>   non-trivial illustration that datatypes can be different on the sender
>   and receiver. If the sender sends b  blocks of length  l each, the
>   receiver can receive them as b*l contiguous elements, either as a
>   contiguous datatype, or as a contiguous buffer of an elementary type;
>   see figure  . In this case, the receiver has no knowledge of the
>   stride of the datatype on the sender. [image: Figure]
>
> [...] In this example a vector type is created only on the sender, in
>   order to send a strided subset of an array; the receiver receives the
>   data as a contiguous block.
>
> As an example of this datatype, consider the example of transposing a
>   matrix, for instance to convert between C and Fortran arrays [...]
>   Suppose that a processor has a matrix stored in C, row-major, layout,
>   and it needs to send a column to another processor. If the matrix is
>   declared as `int M,N; double mat[M][N]`, then a column has  M  blocks
>   of one element, spaced  N  locations apart. In other words:
>
> ```
> MPI_Datatype MPI_column;
> MPI_Type_vector( 
>     /* count= */ M, /* blocklength= */ 1, /* stride= */ N,
>     MPI_DOUBLE, &MPI_column );
> ```
>
> Sending the first column is easy:
>
> ```
> MPI_Send( mat, 1,MPI_column, ... );
> ```
>
> The second column is just a little trickier: you now need to pick out
>   elements with the same stride, but starting at A[0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50077481/2550406%20Gilles%20Gouaillardet's%20answer) .
>
> ```
> MPI_Send( &(mat[0][1]), 1,MPI_column, ... );
> ```
>
> You can make this marginally more efficient (and harder to read) by
>   replacing the index expression by mat+1 .